# Grant s3 user access in bucket level policy

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, boto, minio

I have minio with bucket named "bucket" and IAM user named "user1"

I'll try to grant access to this bucket with Bucket Level Policy

```
client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='localhost:9000')

client.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

```
{
     'Version': '2012-10-17',
     'Statement': [
         {
         "Sid": "1",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Condition": {
             "StringLike": {
                 "arn:aws:iam": [
                     "arn:aws:iam:::user1",
                 ]
             }
         },
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
         ]
        }
     ]
}
```

But I've got error like this

`ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: invalid condition key 'arn:aws:iam'`

Comment: Ideally, you would simply provide the necessary S3 permissions to the IAM user via an IAM policy, not via an S3 bucket policy.

Comment: @jarmod I've problem with IAM policy cause we use Minio with boto3 and boto doesn't provide methods to manipulate IAM policies

Comment: Yes, boto3 provides methods to modify IAM policies. For example [update_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/update_role.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a `Condition`. Instead, use:

```json
{
     'Version': '2012-10-17',
     'Statement': [
         {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/USERNAME",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
             "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
         ]
        }
     ]
}
```

However, it is better to **put the permissions on the IAM User** rather than using a Bucket Policy.

Also, it is **very dangerous** to grant `s3:*` permission to a user. This means they can delete objects from the bucket, make the bucket public (not good for confidential information) and even Delete the bucket. It is better to scope-down the permissions being granted.

In boto3, you can use [`put_user_policy()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/put_user_policy.html):

> Adds or updates an inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM user.

and [`get_user_policy()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/get_user_policy.html):

> Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the specified IAM user.